# NVRAM location on Intel Macs

Tags: macos

Is the NVRAM on Intel Macs mapped in memory? If so, where is the address that it is located at? Apologies if this question is not strictly a 'programming' question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, but the kernel doesn't access NVRAM that way, so likely neither should you.  Short of exhaustively searching memory or figuring out a way to debug/disassemble the EFI implementation, I don't think this is particularly doable.

Access to NVRAM is provided by EFI Variable Services.  (U)EFI doesn't provide an interface to get at the nonvolatile storage for variables.

Going up a level, the kext that implements the NVRAM interface by setting/getting EFI variables is `/System/Library/Extensions/AppleEFIRuntime.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleEFINVRAM.kext`.  It is not open source.

There are APIs available for manipulating NVRAM contents, and the `nvram` tool itself is open source.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually adjust the starting address via

> nvram virt-base=value

Check out Section 8.3.2. in the following [link](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/mac/ch08_03.htm)